# ASP.NET DropDownList - GetSelectedIndices missing one selected item

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Maybe I'm losing my mind - I thought this was straight forward.

```
ListCode.DataTextField = "code_desc";
ListCode.DataValueField = "code_id";
ListCode.DataSource = Foo.GetCodes();
ListCode.DataBind();
```

The selection mode is set to multipls and all is good, about 50 items with appropriate values displays.  Then I select 5 items and submit the form.  I do a

```
int[] indices = ListCode.GetSelectedIndices();
```

and the array only has the first four items that I selected.  It seems that if I select multiple items in the list and submit the form, I'm only able to retrieve all but the last selected item - it doesn't matter if I use GetSelectedIndices or if I iterate through each item in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the count of the array that you get back from "ListCode.GetSelectedIndices()" ? Also, is the control Dropdownlist or listbox?

Comment: You sure that the array really only has four items... e.g. perhaps you're falling for the ol' `for (int i=0;i<indices.getUpperBound(0);i++)` trick. Alternatively, is there any reason that Foo.GetCodes() would return a different list on the postback?

Comment: @jamietre i though of that (the postback question) but no, it was accurate.  It's weird, if there were more than one items selected, the last item was dropped.  I managed to get around it but subsituting a checkboxlist in and that worked like a champ.

Comment: Your tile says `DropDownList`. Are you sure it is a `DropDownList` and not a `ListBox`? There is no support for multi-select using a `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I swapped in a checkboxlist and it worked like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a `ListBox` I assume.  I made the following test app:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstTest" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test4" Value="4" />
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" />

protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int[] selectedIndexes = lstTest.GetSelectedIndices();
    lblTest.Text = selectedIndexes.Length.ToString();
}
```

Seems to work fine so I have to assume it has something to do with your binding or when you are fetching the indicies.  Can you post a trimmed down version of your broken code?